# Generically encapsulating random generators and distrubitons into a class template

Tags: performance, templates, random, variadic-templates, c++17

I previously had a set of classes in one of my older libraries for working with the random number generators and distributions that was written when Visual Studio 2008 - 2010 were common place and before the release of 2012. I was starting a new project in Visual Studio 2017 so I decided to port my original version of the class over.

It was giving me a plethora of errors. So I had to modify the original class, and when I tried to make a generic function to use the above classes, I ended up facing some downfalls due to the fact that you can not partial specialize function templates. After enough frustrations for the past few days; I started over and rewrote the whole class. With the some of the newer features of C++11 & higher; I was able to use variadic templates which truly simplified things once I got use to the required syntax. So now that you have a bit of the history I can move on to my working example.

---

I have this class `Generator` that is working without errors to the best of my knowledge; it compiles, builds and runs without errors and I have tested a handful of different combinations of engines or generators, different seeding techniques with different distributions using their template type `T`.

```
#ifndef GENERATOR_H
#define GENERATOR_H

#include <limits>
#include <chrono>
#include <random>
#include <type_traits>

enum SeedType { USE_CHRONO_CLOCK, USE_RANDOM_DEVICE, USE_SEED_VALUE, USE_SEED_SEQ };

template<class Engine, class Type, template<typename> class Distribution>
class Generator {
public:
    using Clock = std::conditional_t<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::is_steady,
        std::chrono::high_resolution_clock,
        std::chrono::steady_clock>;

private:
    Engine _engine;
    Distribution<Type> _distribution;
    Type _value;

public:    
    template<class... Params>
    explicit Generator( Engine engine, Params... params ) : _engine( engine ) {
        _distribution = Distribution<Type>( params... );
    }

    void seed( SeedType type = USE_RANDOM_DEVICE, std::size_t seedValue = 0, std::initializer_list<std::size_t> list = {} ) {
        switch( type ) {
            case USE_CHRONO_CLOCK:  { _engine.seed( getTimeNow() );  break; }
            case USE_RANDOM_DEVICE: { std::random_device device{};
                                      _engine.seed( device() );      break; }
            case USE_SEED_VALUE:    { _engine.seed( seedValue );     break; }
            case USE_SEED_SEQ:      { std::seed_seq seq( list );
                                      _engine.seed( seq );           break; }
        }
    }

    void generate() { _value = _distribution( _engine ); }

    Type getGeneratedValue() const { return _value; }

    Distribution<Type> getDistribution() const { return _distribution; }

    std::size_t getTimeNow() {
        std::size_t now = static_cast<std::size_t>(Clock::now().time_since_epoch().count());
        return now;
    }    
};

#endif // !GENERATOR_H
```

---

Using it is as simple as this demonstrating a few examples:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include "generator.h"

int main() {            
    // Engine, Seeding Type, & Distribution Combo 1
    std::mt19937 engine1;
    Generator<std::mt19937, short, std::uniform_int_distribution> g1( engine1, 1, 100 );
    g1.seed( USE_RANDOM_DEVICE );

    std::vector<short> vals1;
    for( unsigned int i = 0; i < 200; i++ ) {
        g1.generate();
        auto v = g1.getGeneratedValue();
        vals1.push_back( v );
    }

    int i = 0;
    for( auto& v : vals1 ) {

        if( (i % 10) != 0 ) {
            std::cout << std::setw( 3 ) << v << " ";
        } else {
            std::cout << '\n' << std::setw( 3 ) << v << " ";
        }       
        i++;
    }
    std::cout << "\n\n";

    // Engine, Seeding Type, & Distribution Combo 2
    std::ranlux48 engine2;
    std::initializer_list<std::size_t> list2{ 3, 7, 13, 17, 27, 31, 43 };   
    Generator<std::ranlux48, unsigned, std::binomial_distribution> g2( engine2, 50, 0.75 );
    g2.seed( USE_SEED_SEQ, std::size_t(7), list2 );

    std::vector<unsigned> vals2;
    for( int i = 0; i < 200; i++ ) {
        g2.generate();
        auto v = g2.getGeneratedValue();
        vals2.push_back( v );
    }

    i = 0;
    for( auto& v : vals2 ) {    
        if( (i % 10) != 0 ) {
            std::cout << std::setw( 3 ) << v << " ";
        } else {
            std::cout << '\n' << std::setw( 3 ) << v << " ";
        }
        i++;
    }
    std::cout << "\n\n";

    // Engine, Seeding Type, & Distribution Combo 3
    std::minstd_rand engine3;
    Generator<std::minstd_rand, float, std::gamma_distribution> g3( engine3, 0.22222f, 0.7959753f );
    g3.seed( USE_CHRONO_CLOCK );

    std::vector<float> vals3;    
    for( int i = 0; i < 200; i++ ) {
        g3.generate();
        auto v = g3.getGeneratedValue();
        vals3.push_back( v );
    }

    i = 0;
    for( auto& v : vals3 ) {

        if( (i % 5 ) != 0 ) {
            std::cout << std::setw( 12 ) << v << " ";
        } else {
            std::cout << '\n' << std::setw( 12 ) << v << " ";
        }
        i++;
    }
    std::cout << "\n\n";    

    std::cout << "\nPress any key and enter to quit.\n";
    std::cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

---

Is this an appropriate way to generically encapsulate the random generators & distributions? Are there any 'gotchas' that I'm missing? Finally, can this be improved for efficiency purposes? Or would it be more appropriate to ask this question on Code Review?

Comment: I would have joined `generate` and `getGeneratedValue` in an overload of `operator()`, but that's questionable. I also agree that if you can't find any error in your code, Code Review may be more appropriate.

Comment: @Bob__ okay I wasn't sure, and thank you for the suggestion. This is only just the shell of the working class; I can always improve it; and add other features.